# Breaking Long Paragraph Into Read More Link

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is I am trying to get some testimonials from the database and need to echo them in a div. The DIV has created with fix width and height values. In this case I need to display every testimonials with a link of 'read more' to full one. Here in the DIV I want to limit to only 50 words from the testimonials... can any body tell me how  I can do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this-

```
echo wordwrap(substr($str, 50), 20, "<br />\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

If the container has fixed height and width values, then limiting the amount of text by character is only fool-proof if you're using a monospaced typeface. Why not do it the CSS way?

```
.truncated {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow): IE 6+, Safari 4+, Firefox 7+, Opera 11+ and Chrome 10+.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like,

echo substr(strip_tags($str), 0, 50)."...";